# Show/hide iframes with an event listener

Tags: javascript, iframe, event-handling

I am fairly new to javascript/web development but I am tasked in a group project to create image comparison sliders to an existing webpage.  There is a map (ArcGIS web map) on the page, and I have found a service that hosts image comparison sliders in iframes.

I was thinking that I could use an EventListener to listen for when the user clicks on a point on the map, and then it would display the corresponding iframe, and hide the last one.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is definitely possible in Javascript. All you have to do is setup a function to be called on an `onclick` event, and in this function you must obtain the required click coordinates (using `event.clientX` and `event.clientY`). Based on these coordinates you can figure out the required iFrame number.